# How do I find a value in a range of strings

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have data that is (mostly) just numbers:

```
id   start       end
1    1420010     1421011
2    B420010     B421011
3    1420010     1422011
4    7505017     7505017
```

It does appear that it has been padded with spaces in many cases.

I want to be able to pass in a value and have it return all IDs that has that value in the range. Initially, I thought I had it working when I tried: `where start >= '7505017' and end <= '7505017'`.

When I tried doing `where start >= '1420010' and end <= '1420010'`, it doesn't return any results and it should. Ideally, I should be able to look up any value in that range and have it return a value. I am drawing a blank as to why I am having the issue.

I have tried padding the beginning with spaces and the end with Zs.

```
(start >= @org + '                 ' and end <= @org + 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ')
```

What am I missing? Please note that the user will only be passing in the full 7 digits (which will be controlled by the UI).

Comment: String comparisons behave differently to numeric ones.  How are you handling the IDs that start with letters as in your row ID = 2?  Is that 'greater' or 'less' than 1, 2, 7, etc?

Comment: @MisterPositive  The relevant parts (`where` clauses) are in the question already.

Comment: RTrim(LTrim(Replace(yourColumn ' ', ''))) To get rid of spaces and such.  As @iamdave stated comparing character data versus numeric data is different.

Comment: You can ignore the preceding spaces with `LTRIM()` but your biggest problem is going to be what @iamdave stated. Numeric versus character, case sensitivity, etc all regarding unicode sort order

Comment: @MisterPositive RTRIM usually doesn't matter for SQL comparisions... `SELECT 'true' WHERE 'pad' = 'pad                     '`

Comment: To illustrate this: `select case when '4' > '1000' then 1 else 0 end` will return `1`

Comment: @iamdave With our data, that shouldn't be an issue. The Bs and Ms (only two we have at this time and they are only upper case) are separate ranges from the ones that start with a number. I am only looking for a number within that range. This is security for a financial package. I am trying to build some audit reports so we can see who has access to xxxxxxx account. And we will only be searching by the 7 digit number.

Comment: what version of sql, 2012,2008,etc?

Comment: @scsimon 12.0.5000.0 Which should be 2014 SP 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirements, it may be as simple as

```
Declare @YourTable table (id int,start varchar(50),[end] varchar(50))
Insert into @YourTable values 
(1,'1420010','1421011'),
(2,'B420010','B421011'),
(3,'1420010','1422011'),
(4,'7505017','7505017')

Declare @Org varchar(50) = '1420010'

Select * 
 From  @YourTable 
 Where @Org between Start and [End]
```

Returns

```
id  start   end
1   1420010 1421011
3   1420010 1422011
```

Comment: This is essentially what the OP is doing already and it isn't working for them, for reasons laid out in the comments...

Comment: For whatever reason, this is working. Even with the Bs and Ms.

Comment: @iamdave No it is not what OP was doing.   Not surprising, it seems to be working for him,

Comment: @MikeWills I suspect you were just over-thinking it.  :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are confident in your data, you can simply convert the parts you need to `int` and go from there.  If you are ignoring your `B......` values for now, you can do something like:

```
declare @a table(id int, s nvarchar(50), e nvarchar(50));

insert into @a values
 (1,'1420010','421011')
,(2,'B420010','B421011')
,(3,'1420010','1422011')
,(4,'7505017','7505017')

select *
from @a
where case when isnumeric(s) = 1
            then cast(s as int)
            else null
            end >= 1420010
    and case when isnumeric(e) = 1
            then cast(e as int)
            else null
            end <= 1421020;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to look at the numeric ones only, you can use:

```
DELCARE @org INT = 1421011
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(INT,start) >= @org AND TRY_CONVERT(INT,end) <= @org
```

Comment: As `try_convert` is available, this is the superior solution for finding the numeric ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Lets start with an easy one

```
select top (100) id, start, len(start), end, len(end) 
from table 
order by id asc 

select top (100) id, start, len(start), end, len(end) 
from table 
order by id desc

select top (100) id, start, len(start), end, len(end) 
from table  
where ltrim(start) = '1420010'
order by id asc

select top (100) id, start, len(start), end, len(end) 
from table  
where ltrim(start) >= '1420010'
order by id asc
```